Probability that realization of gaussian process is bounded by a certain value
I am interested in the following: Let $(g(x))_{x \in [0,a)}$ be a gaussian process, i.e. $g \sim \mathcal{GP}(0, K)$ with a suitable Covariance Kernel $K$. I am interested in the following probability:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(g \leq \kappa) = \mathbb{P}(\bigcap_x [g(x) \leq \kappa(x)]),
\end{align}
where $\kappa:[0,a) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ s.t. \ x \mapsto \kappa_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant function. So i am interested in the probability that a realization of the gaussian process is bounded from above by $\kappa_0$ on the interval $[0,a)$. Intuitively, I thought that it should just be equal to $\mathbb{P}(Z \leq \kappa_0)$, where $Z \sim N(0, 1)$, however, the variance (or more precicely, the covariance kernel) should play a more important role right? Also the length of the interval, $t$, should matter in some ways I would imagine. Are there any results on probabilites like this? Or am I missing something obvious? I could not seem to find literature/webpages on such questions.
For Context: I tried to calculate the probability with some functional integral theory and I am not sure about the results.
Also, I see that in principle what you could do to get the probability is to consider the random vector $G := (g(0), g(\frac{a}{k}),...,g(\frac{(k-1)a}{k}))$ which is jointly normal with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ given by evaluations of the covariance kernel $K$ at the respective grid points. Then using $G= \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} Z$ with $Z \sim N(0, I)$ you can rewritte the probability in terms of the standard normal cdf and then take the limit, however you will need the Cholesky decomposition of the matrix $\Sigma$ which is quite general. There should be an easier way to obtain the result, right?

Given a Gaussian Process $g \sim \mathcal{GP}(0, K(\cdot, \cdot'))$ and an upper bound $\kappa_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, what you're looking for can be more clearly stated as
$$\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{x \in [0, a)} [g(x) \le \kappa_0]\right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{x \in [0, a)} g(x) \le \kappa_0\right)$$
for some $a \ge 0$. Bounds on the reverse probability (i.e. the probability that the GP is greater than some real value) are known as exceedence probability bounds and are very well studied in the GP literature.
One of the main warhorses for tackling such questions is the Borell-TIS inequality. To state it, assume we have a set $T$ indexing the GP and define $||g|| \triangleq \sup_{t \in T} |g_t|$ and $\sigma^2_T \triangleq \sup_{t \in T} \mathbb{E} \left[ |g_t|^2 \right]$. Then, assuming $||g||$ is almost surely finite we have that $\mathbb{E} \left[ ||g|| \right]$ and $\sigma^2_T$ are also finite and that for any $v > 0$ it holds that
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P} \left( ||g|| > \mathbb{E} \left[ ||g|| \right] + v \right) \le \exp \left( \frac{-v^2}{2\sigma^2_T} \right)
    \end{equation}
Most of the time our handle on the expectation term comes from Dudley's theorem. The theorem uses the canonical pseudometric defined for any $s, t \in T$ as
\begin{equation}
    d(s, t) = \sqrt{\mathbb{E} \left[\left( g(s) - g(t) \right)^2 \right]}
\end{equation}
and assumes that $T$ is d-compact. Then, fixing some radius $\epsilon > 0$ of d-balls, it states that there exists a universal constant $C$ such that
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E} \left[ \sup_{t \in T} g_t \right] \le C \int_{0}^{\frac{\delta_T}{2}} \sqrt{\log N(T, d, \epsilon)} d\epsilon
\end{equation}
where $N(T, d, \epsilon)$ denotes the entropy number, that is, the smallest number of balls whose union covers $T$ and $\delta_T$ is the diameter. With relatively mild assumptions on the entropy number you can derive sufficiently good bounds on the exceedence probability.
Importantly, you can also see that the bounds non-trivially depend on the kernel (through the variance terms and also the pseudometric) and the index set, as you would expect.
There is a lot more one can do (e.g. with comparison inequalities) and there is also a lot of interplay between necessary and sufficient conditions even in the above (e.g. when you have a.s. finiteness, d-compactness, stationarity, continuous sample paths etc). A good reference for the above is Adler's Random Fields and Geometry.
Of course, there are special cases where the exceedence probability can be computed in closed form in a much simpler way. This is the case for Brownian motion-type processes, which are in fact GPs. For example, going back to your initial question, for the standard Wiener process, which is a GP with kernel $K(s, t) = min(s, t)$, we immediately have the result that
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in [0, a)} W(t) \le \kappa_0 \right) = 1 - \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in [0, a)} W(t) \le \kappa_0 \right) = 1 - 2 \mathbb{P}\left( W(a) \ge \kappa_0 \right) = 2 \Phi \left( \frac{\kappa_0}{\sqrt{a}} \right) - 1
\end{equation}
by the reflection principle. But to state something in much greater generality as you attempted, you need to go look into these exceedence probabilities for Gaussian random fields.
